# Can we set Retention policy to particular Folders/Objects in GCS Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I want to delete particular Folder/Objects after prescribed time, can we set a Retention Policy or Object lifecycles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set lifecycle on a bucket. After a period of time, you can chose to delete the objects that match the rules.

It's not possible at object or folder level (because folder doesn't exist!)

Comment: oh, can't we set to group of objects? I mean listing/grouping certain objects and setting on them!

Comment: No, "groups" don't exist on Cloud Storage. As I said, directory doesn't exist, it's just a convention, when the object name prefix contains `/`, a directory is interpreted by the UI. Anyway, putting a lifecycle on a prefix (as you can search object per prefix) is a good feature idea! You can open a feature request here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by providing prefix of the files you want to delete under "Set Rule Scopes".

E.g.:

Bucket: mybucket
File: folder1/folder2/file.csv

If you want to delete file files inside folder2, you can mention prefix as "folder1/folder2" while creating lifecycle rule.